# numpy - is there a way to cause multiple increments at arr[1, [0, 2, 0, 2, 0]] += 1

Tags: numpy

## Background

`+1` occurs only once for each element although each indexed element is referenced multiple times.

```
a = np.arange(12).reshape((3, 4))
b = a.copy()
print(a)
---
[[ 0  1  2  3]
 [ 4  5  6  7]
 [ 8  9 10 11]]

a[1, [0, 2, 0, 2, 0]] += 1  #  a[1][0] referenced 3 times and a[1][2] 2 times
print(a-b)
---
[[0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 1 0]   # <--- +1 occurs only once for a[1][0] and a[1][2]
 [0 0 0 0]]
```

## Question

Is there a way to create a sort of accumulative addition like below in a numpy native way?

```
# Result a
[[ 0  1  2  3]
 [ 7  5  8  7]    <--- +1 three times on a[1][0] and twice on a[1][2]
 [ 8  9 10 11]]

# a-b
[[0 0 0 0]
 [3 0 2 0]   # <--- +3 for a[1][0] and +2 for a[1][2]
 [0 0 0 0]]
```

One way can be reduce-like, similar to map/reduce word counting, but would like to know if there is a native numpy way.

[image]

Comment: I think you want `np.add.at(a[1], [0, 2, 0, 2, 0], 1)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're looking for is [`numpy.ufunc.at`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html). Here is how you can use it in your case:

```python
np.add.at(a, (1, [0, 2, 0, 2, 0]), 1)

print(a - b)
# [[0 0 0 0]
#  [3 0 2 0]
#  [0 0 0 0]]
```

From the docs:

> Performs unbuffered in place operation on operand ‘a’ for elements specified by ‘indices’. For addition ufunc, this method is equivalent to `a[indices] += b`, except that results are accumulated for elements that are indexed more than once. For example, `a[[0,0]] += 1` will only increment the first element once because of buffering, whereas `add.at(a, [0,0], 1)` will increment the first element twice.

Answer (score 1):

As long as this accumulative addition can work along one axis at a time - you can utilize `collections.Counter`.

Consider the following:

```py
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter

a = np.arange(12).reshape((3, 4))
b = a.copy()

add_lst = [0, 2, 0, 2, 0]
add_lst = Counter(add_lst)
a[1, list(add_lst.keys())] += list(add_lst.values())
print(a-b)
```

Outputs:

```py
[[0 0 0 0]
 [3 0 2 0]
 [0 0 0 0]]
```